# Android/Eclipse: how to prioritize a local over a library package

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I am using Eclipse and I have an Android application composed of two packages, a core package which is the app and a Settings package which stores a series of global settings for the app (e.g. in-app purchase market key for the app). The app also imports a library (e.g. an in-app wrapper lib), which in turn also uses a copy of that aforementioned global Settings package.

How I've implemented this, to date, is with three projects; the App, the Library and a third one for for the Settings (as a library). The Settings Lib exported as a Jar, then put in the build path of the Library and referenced the Library from the top level app, so to avoid the dreaded "Multiple dex files" error (as will happen if I reference the MySettings project from MyLib). Overall, it looks a bit like this:

```
MyApp (MyLib referenced)
- Core_App_Logic
- Settings

MyLib (MySettings.jar in build path)
- Lib_Logic

MySettings
- Settings
```

Resources are prioritized correctly; those in MyApp will be used rather than those in MyLib. However, while MyApp will use the MyApp.Settings package, MyLib will instead use the MySettings.Settings one.

Am I missing something with this approach, or should I be looking at a completely different one?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my own question, which I can do because I left out some information in my original question that was turned out to be very relevant. In the end it was a silly mistake by me - nonetheless, this answer may help others in the future as I am certain I have no monopoly on silly mistakes.

In essence, there are no problems with the above design. My error was in the Settings classes, I set, for example, the various variables I wanted to use and override as:

```
public final static String MyVar = "Foobar";
```

Which naturally meant that MyApp.Settings.MyVar could not override Settings.MyVar as it was marked as **final**. So I removed the final tokens to all my settings variables in Settings and MyApp.Settings overrode them correctly.